# Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{k^n}{n!} =0$ for all $k$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{k^n}{n!}=0 \, \forall\:k\in \mathbb{R}$$

I have tried to find an $N$ in term of epsilon in the definition of limit, but to no avail. I've tried log, but $\log (n!)=\log(1)+\log(2)+...+\log(n)$ does not seem to help here.

Could you help me with this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for the edit. It was very helpful.

Comment: I do not know how this could help : I suppose you noticed that the sum of all your terms is "Exp[k]-1".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the ratio

$$\frac{\frac{k^{n + 1}}{(n + 1)!}}{\frac{k^n}{n!}} = \frac{n!}{(n + 1)!} \frac{k^{n + 1}}{k^n} = \frac{k}{n + 1} \to 0$$

as $n \to \infty$. Hence by the [ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test), the sum

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{k^n}{n!}$$ converges for each $k \in \mathbb{R}$. In particular, the terms of the sequence being summed must tend to $0$.

Comment: It is important to note that if the $a_n>0$ then $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$ implies that $a_n<r^n$ for $n$ sufficiently large, whence $a_n\to 0$. In particular, since $\sum r^n<+\infty$, $\sum a_n<+\infty$ so $\sum a_n$ converges. The fact the series converges is an extra, so to speak.

Comment: I thought I had to prove that the limit is 0 with the Epsilon definition of limit. But this Ratio-Test is helpful and illuminating and made me read the question once again, and to my "dismay", I only had to "show" that the limit is 0. Thank you for your answer.